# Facebook exception in Android

Tags: android, facebook, exception

ALL,

I am getting "Cannot request publish or manage authorization with no permissions." on the following piece of code. What is wrong?

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
    final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_stream");
    OpenRequest openRequest=new Session.OpenRequest(this);
    openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
    openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);
    openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.ONLY_ME);
    openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
    //session.openForPublish(openRequest);
    session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
} else {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
}
```

on either calls to openForPublish().

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, never mind that.
I need to call "session.openForPublish( openRequest );" and everything works. I guess it was some temporary glitch.

But then for some reason I am getting another exception "NoClassDefFoundError" on accessing Facebook login page "R.layout.com_facebook_login_activity_layout".

Any idea?

Comment: open a different question on that regard. And post your code and your logcat.